# React Native Material Top Tab freeze after adding ScrollView to it parent component

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create an Instagram or Twitter profile page look, I was able to do some pleasing things but when I add ScrollView to the parent component, Material Top Tab freeze and fails to display file, image below
[image: The freezed Material Top Tab after adding scrollview to it parent component]

After removing the scrollview, this is the screenshot of that below.
[image: Material Top Tab after removing scrollview from it parent component]